# 1 or 2 repositories for project in git

Tags: git, perforce

I come from a Perforce environment, but I understand the basics and some internals of `git`, but workflow wise I am stuck with a problem.

I am in the process of converting a perforce depot into git. In my Perforce depo I have 2 master branches (`core` and `master`) where `core` gets integrated into `master` regularly.

```
//depot/core/...
   | +-/feature/core_feature1/...
   | +-/feature/core_feature2/...
   |
   v
//depot/master/...
     +-/feature/master_feature1/...
     +-/feature/master_feature2/...
```

Can I keep this concept in **git** as well or should `core` become a separate repository? Because `core==>master` but never `master==>core`. So I am not sure which branch should become the `master` branch. I think it should be `master` but how can I setup a "merge-integrate-dependency" that in git two projects contain different amount of "states" or files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use subtree or submodule.

#### `submodule`

- **submodule** is usually for component-based (microservices) and the content is stored in a separate repo but included" in the main repo as a component.

#### `subtree`

- **subtree** usually a single repository where your all code is stored in a single repo usually in different branches which are again usually used to develop a separate line of code.

---

## `submodule`

[image]

[image]

---

### `subtree`

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! That makes sense now to me

Answer (score 3):

Definitely one repository, you will only make your life hard by having two. Almost all operations are easier within a single repository, and you're not gaining anything significant by having two.

I don't understand your flow well enough to weigh in on "which should be master" but I will point out that master is nothing more than a name. It's a *very* widely-held convention, and it's the name of the "default default branch", so to speak, but `master` is really just another branch, not privileged in any way. You're free to set up any flow you like, use master how you like, or even not have a branch named `master` at all, as long as you and your collaborators are happy.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That definition for *master* is more clear to me now